# java - final protected static class for class extending another class

Tags: java, android, oop

I have a Record class. In this Record class i have a save() method which saves data to a database. I have several other classes that extend this Record class, for example, a Person class. In my Person class i would like to define the database table name and columns for the People database table. I would like to make these final static properties that all instances of Person reference. How do I let Record, the extended class, know this property will exist in all extended class? How do i define a static property for a class that the base class knows exists?

Would this be an appropriate use of an interface?

```
public class Record {
    protected String table_name;
    protected String[] table_columns;

    private void save(){
        //save data based on table_name and table_columns;
    }
}

public class Person extends Record{
    protected final static String table_name = "People";
    protected final static String[] table_columns = {"_id","name"}
}
```

Comment: Why do you want the base class to have this property, ie what is the goal ?

Comment: i want the base class to be able to save the record to the correct database table and be aware of what columns it needs to populate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why the need for `static final`?

If you make `Record` abstract and change the table name and table columns to be abstract methods, you will be required to implement them in subclasses (and `Record` will be ensured of their presence).

I'm not sure why instances of `Person` would need to access this information, but it would still be possible, if necessary.

```
public abstract class Record {
  protected abstract String getTableName();
  protected abstract String[] getTableColumns();

  private void save(){
    //save data based on getTableName() and getTableColumns();
  }
}

public class Person extends Record {
  protected String getTableName() {
    return "People";
  }
  protected String[] getTableColumns() {
    return new String[] { "_id", "name" };
  }
}
```

Comment: like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911278/inherit-a-static-variable-in-java/3911294

Comment: ooooohhhhhh. Never understood the use of abstract classes and interfaces until now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think a good way to achieve your reqs is doing something like this:
(I assume Record should be abstract)

```
public abstract class Record {
    protected abstract String getTableName();
    protected abstract String[] getTableColumns();

    private void save(){
        String table_name = getTableName();
        String[] table_columns = getTableColumns();
        //save data based on table_name and table_columns;
    }
}

public class Person extends Record{
    protected final static String table_name = "People";
    protected final static String[] table_columns = {"_id","name"}

    protected String getTableName(){
         return table_name;
    }

    protected String[] getTableColumns(){
        return table_columns;
    }
}
```