# Changing static double in other classes

Tags: java, inheritance, static

So I am making a ticket booth that sales three tickets using inheritance and polymorphism.  the output needs to look like this.

Regular Season:

```
Ticket type: Walkup, Number: 123, Price: 10.00
Ticket type: Advance, Number: 234, Price: 7.50
Ticket type: Student Advance, Number: 345, Price: 3.75 (ID Required)
```

Finals:

```
Ticket type: Walkup, Number: 321, Price: 12.00
Ticket type: Advance, Number: 432, Price: 9.00
Ticket type: Student Advance, Number: 543, Price: 4.50 (ID Required)
```

My output is this.

Regular Season:

```
Ticket type:  Walkup,  Number:  123,  Price:  10.00
Ticket type:  Advance,  Number:  234,  Price:  10.00
Ticket type:  Student Advance,  Number:  345,  Price:  10.00
```

Finals:

```
Ticket type:  Walkup,  Number:  321,  Price:  12.00
Ticket type:  Advance,  Number:  432,  Price:  12.00
Ticket type:  Student Advance,  Number:  543,  Price:  12.00
```

So my question is how do i change a static double, price, in my code to make it those prices without changing the whole price to what i set it to.

heres my code:

```
public abstract class Ticket {

    protected String ticketNumber;
    protected static double price = 10.00;
    protected String ticketName;

    // constructor so i can change my ticket number in the main as a parameter
    public Ticket(String string)  {
        this.ticketNumber = string;
    }

    // get name in other classes
    public String getName()  {
        return ticketName;
    }

    // get price
    public double getPrice()  {
        return price;
    }

    // so i can chang the price in the main 
    public static void setPrice(double price) {
        Ticket.price = price;
    }

    // toString method so i can print my descriptive information.
    public String toString()  {
        String result = String.format("\tTicket type:  %s,  Number:  %s,  Price:  %.2f", getName(), ticketNumber, getPrice());
        return result;
    }
}

public class WalkUpTicket extends Ticket {

    public WalkUpTicket(String string) {
        super(string);

    }

    public String getName()  {
        return this.ticketName = "Walkup";
    }

}

public class AdvanceTicket extends Ticket {

    public AdvanceTicket(String string) {
        super(string);
    }
    public String getName()  {
        return "Advance";   
    }   
}
public class StudentAdvanceTicket extends AdvanceTicket {

    public StudentAdvanceTicket(String string) {
        super(string);

    }

    public String getName()  {
        return "Student Advance";
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have the code for the main method?

Comment: The whole point of static is theres only one for all instances. and you have it in the abstract Ticket class.. so all tickets will get set to that price.. you need a static price variable for each ticket type.. and in those classes some way to change it for finals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static instance variables are shared across every instance of the same class. They're *class* bound, not *instance* bound.

As mentioned, you need to remove the static price from the `Ticket` class and instead put it in each of the classes that extend it. Since the variable is class-bound, you need to have one for each of the subclasses. You'll also have to create a `setPrice()` method *in each subclass* to modify each type's price.

Comment: its a requirement in my class to use it.

Comment: but i imagine he wants all subclasses to share a static price... all advance tickets have x price all walkup tickets have y price.. he needs static just in the subclasses not in the higher one

Answer (score 0):

The best compromise for this design pattern is shown here [Inherit a Static Variable in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911278/inherit-a-static-variable-in-java) .. how to inherit a static member into your subclases, from the top answer:

```
abstract class Parent {
public abstract String getACONSTANT();
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public static final String ACONSTANT = "some value";
    public String getACONSTANT() { return ACONSTANT; }
}
```